# Photoshop: Actions to Font Size?

Tags: text, adobe, action, photoshop, layer

I have to edit few hundred pages of Photoshop files that has lots of text layers.  I have to change font style, font size, letter spacing, ect on each layer on each page.  I am trying to see if I can use actions to expedite this

---

**What I tried, and did not work**:
Took the route of creating actions as usual.  This recorded everything I wanted to do, EXCEPT, it wanted to change text content to what was in the recorded layer when the action was recorded, every time, with every layer.

**What I need to do**:
Create a Photoshop action to change font style, font size in a text layer, but **NOT CHANGE ACTUAL TEXT** within it self.  Is this possible?

---

Comment: Can you edit your question and specify exactly what you want to change (which font, what size, what spacing and what else, if anything) and also say if there are any exceptions e.g. not fonts under 12pt, not base layers, only red ones, change all 14pt to 18pt, but all 16pt to 22pt? Thank you. Also what platform are you on Windows/Mac?

Comment: Hello Mark,  Thanks for the reply.  Shawn Taylor below answered my question precisely.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this by selecting the text layer(single click, not double), not the text itself, and make the edit in the "character" window, as opposed to the text toolbar.